# what the tag <?= ?> means in Google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, template-engine

Is the tag `<?= ?>` a specific syntax of Google scripts or it could work in a pure html/javascript page? Is there any description for it?

That is similar to `<?=$a; ?>` PHP tag but I doubted when I saw this: `<? var foo = "test"; ?>`.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, these bits of code are referred to as 'scriptlets' in GAS documentation. They are Apps Script syntax for server-side HTML rendering.

Before HTML content is sent to your browser for client-side rendering all scripts between **<? ?>** and **<?! ?>** are executed and their output gets appended to the template. 
It could also be just plain text between these tags instead of scripts. 
Scriptlets get executed when you convert an HtmlTemplate to a HtmlOutput object in GAS:

```
 //HtmlTemplate instance
 var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplate("<a href='<?!= www.google.com ?>'>Google</a>"); 

 //HtmlOutputInstance - calling evaluate() fires off the scriptlets and 
 //creates HTML output that is ready to be sent to the client. 
 var htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate(); 

 //Logs <a href='www.google.com'> Google </a>
 Logger.log(htmlOutput.getContent());
```

The short answer is no. You can't run scriptlets directly in your browser - they are  executed on Google Servers. You are correct that there are many templating engines that serve the same function but are implemented differently.